# Software recommendation request: deciding whether a system of polynomial equations is solvable by radicals

Tags: computational-geometry, mathematical-software

The following system of equations comes from a very simple geometric figure I have to deal with a lot at work. Here $r_0,r_1,r_2$ and $L$ are known parameters, and the $x_i$s are the coordinates I'm after.

1. $x_0^2 + x_3^2 = r_0^2$
2. $(x_2-L)^2 + x_4^2 = r_2^2$
3. $x_3 = r_1 + \tfrac{1}{2}x_5(x_0 - x_1)^2$
4. $x_4 = r_1 + \tfrac{1}{2}x_5(x_2 - x_1)^2$
5. $x_0 + x_3 x_5(x_0 - x_1) = 0$
6. $(x_2-L) + x_4 x_5(x_2 - x_1) = 0$

I'm currently solving these numerically. This works perfectly well, but is (a) needlessly expensive if I don't have to do it and (b) extremely unsatisfying given the simple form of my equations.

**My question is simply this:** is there a piece of open-source (or otherwise free) software I can use to tell me - quickly and for certain - whether this system (and in future possibly others like it) can be solved explicitly in terms of radicals?

Comment: No chance: see the explanation in https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=153693 .

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll have a read and play with the demo a bit :)

Comment: The pdf: https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/download.aspx?SF=153693/GroebnerTipsTechniques.pdf is really nice. I've heard of Groebner bases but I've never taken the time to learn what they are or what they're used for; nice to have an accessible intro.

Comment: Over the reals?

Comment: Over the reals yes.